# LibGDX texture distortion issue

Tags: java, libgdx

Whatever reason if windows size different than default 512x384 every texture is distorted i tried other viewports but it didn't help.

[random pixels larger than others and etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BvPh.png)

```
public class PartyScreen extends AbstractScreen {
    
    /* View */
    private Viewport gameViewport;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    
    public PartyScreen(PokemonGame app) {
        super(app);
        
        gameViewport = new ScalingViewport(Scaling.fit, 512, 384);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {}

    @Override
    public void hide() {}

    @Override
    public void pause() {}

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        gameViewport.apply();
        batch.begin();
        //512x384 image
        batch.draw(getApp().getAssetManager().get("res/graphics/party/background.png", Texture.class), 0, 0, 512, 384);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        batch.getProjectionMatrix().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, 512, 384);
        gameViewport.update(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {}
}
```